# Does sql pre and deploy runs in one session

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have `SQL VS` project with one `Customers.PreDeployment1.sql` file:

```
DROP TABLE Customers
```

My question is, why after the deletion is happens, the `Customers.sql` (`Build` action) is not running (the table is not getting created in `sql server`)?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [First_Name] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
    [Last_Name] NCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

I couldn't find any explanation for that... maybe because it consider it as one session?

Comment: Look through your deployment script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the deletion doesn't happen until after visual studio has done its diff/compare and generated the script.

So the when the diff is performed (and the deploy script is created), the customers table is still in the DB, VS then adds pre-deploy and post deploy to the change script, then runs it.

I'm sure there's a good reason for this behaviour, but I've never found it.  There are a few ways around the problem, but its not clear what you're trying to achieve by dropping the table in the predeploy?

Comment: It was a demo I gave about this question was raised during the session. I've found it very interesting :)